# calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmHour); is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: android, android-alarms, android-calendar

I am setting an alarm for which I take the Hour and Minutes from a `TextView` and the AM/PM through a `Spinner`. Here is how I initialize the `Calendar` object:

```
Calendar calen = Calendar.getInstance();
calen.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmHour); //alarmHour from TextView
calen.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmMinute); //alarmMinute from TextView
calen.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calen.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

if(amorpm.equals("PM") //amorpm from Spinner
{
    calen.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
}
else
{
    calen.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
}
```

The problem is the **Hour** value of this `Calendar` object is sometimes correct i.e. the value which the user enters in the `TextView` (and it is always 1 to 12). But sometimes, the value is equal to the current Hour. For example, if the current time is **11:30 pm**, and I set the alarm for **9:30 am**, then the **Hour** field has the value **11**. One strange thing is that when I change the name of the `Calendar` object to something else, say **cal**, it works. But wont work later. What could be wrong ?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the solution is to call `calen.set(Calendar.HOUR, alarmHour);` instead of `calen.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmHour);`

The trouble is you are setting the `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` field and **then** setting the AM/PM field. "Hour of day" is hour in the full 24-hour day, and therefore using it in conjuction with AM/PM doesn't make sense. According to the Java documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), when setting the time of day, if conflicting information is presented, then the most recently set information will be used according to the following combinations:

> HOUR_OF_DAY
>
> AM_PM + HOUR

Because you are setting the AM/PM field after the hour, the hour is taken from the `Calendar.HOUR` field, which is of course initialised to the current hour when you create the instance.

The naming of the variable is, of course, a red herring. That can't possibly affect it.

Comment: That is indeed the mistake I am making. But I just noticed that when I select "PM" from the spinner and enter alarm hour "12" in `HOUR`, then it changes "PM" to "AM" in the alarm. Similarly, choosing "AM" and "12" changes it to "PM". It works fine for non-12 values though.

Comment: `Calendar.HOUR` is only supposed to take the values 0-11 (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR) so it's probably trying to do something intelligent with rolling the AM/PM forward when you set it as 12.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I decided to take values in `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` and set AM/PM through my own logic since in the app I am taking values in 12-hour format only.